# Как компилировать с++ компилятором от Visual Studio 2017 через терминал?

Tags: c++, компиляция, visual-studio-2017, командная-строка

Вот здесь: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1&v=5Y9Cx5cLM50
как раз то что мне и нужно.

Но проблема в том, в VS2017 при выполнении их bat файлов создаются "command prompt shortcut". Когда открываешь такой ярлык, то открывается командная строка в которой есть команда **cl** и все что нужно. 
Но в просто открытом терминале нету команды cl. А мне она как раз в терминале и нужна, при чем в любом. Что бы я мог ее использовать как, например, команду dir или cd.

Comment: Интересно, зачем? Ну, если так хочется - настройте несколько десятков переменных среды соответствующим образом, и работайте...

Comment: `Msbuild <имя.проекта>` и будет вам счастье :)

Comment: А зачем, это очевидно, студия это ужасные тормоза, и запускать ее для мелких правок чтоб собрать что-то, просто не разумно, да и вредно для нервной системы :)

Comment: Студия по функционалу - хорошая.
Но меня просто бесит ее автокомплит (ну и не только автокомплит). 
Я бы хотел использовать VS Code. Но это что-то среднее между просто редактором кода и IDE, и так просто с++ там не настроить.

А так как к компилятору VS у меня нет никаких вопросов, то было бы неплохо его и использовать. Тем более у них даже раздел такой есть:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=vs-2017

Плюс, если бы оно было так как в старых видео - то это более чем нормально. А в VS 2017 оно что-то стало сильно запутанней.

Comment: Вероятнее всего придется использовать другой компилятор, типа g++

Comment: "настройте несколько десятков переменных среды соответствующим образом, и работайте..."

Они у себя в гайде подряд раз 10  разными словами написали, что они не рекомендуют так делать :)

Comment: Обычно пишут bat скрипт который либо сам находит и вызывает `vcvarsall.bat`, либо требует чтобы его запускали в Developer Command Prompt for VS.

Comment: "бесит ее автокомплит" - шта? Тем более непонятно, на кой вам сдалась VS Code, которая мало того, что тяжелее студии (хотя у них там подразумевалось наоборот), так еще будет использовать урезанный автокомплит по образцу обычной студии.

Comment: Вы использовали VS Code хоть какое-то время?
Автокомплит у него уж точно более функциональный чем у VS.
Даже для c++. 

(я ее использую в основном для TS - по удобству использования, автокомплиту и прочим штукам - VS CODE - просто на 1 месте и доказательство здесь: https://2018.stateofjs.com/other-tools/#text_editors).

Да для компилируемый языков это может быть немного странно и не уверен что он меня устроит. Но попробовать нужно.

Comment: Если хотите так компилироваиь) то консоль VS называется Developer Command Prompt, для справки по командам пишите `cl /? `

Comment: Я знаю это. Но мне не нужна какая-то специальная консоль. Мне нужно что бы команда cl была в любой консоле (хотя мне уже перехотелось использовать компилятор от VS, лучше уже gcc)